# Rails 4 - Devise - admin approval of new users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to figure out how to follow this devise tutorial to add 'approved' to the user model.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in

I have everything set up as shown in the tutorial, except when I save it all and try to click on the link called:

```
<%= link_to "Users awaiting approval", :action => "index", :approved => "false" %>
```

I get an error called:

```
undefined method `find_all_by_approved' for #<Class:0x007fbc5cf34dd0>
```

It highlights the second line of this users/index action:

```
def index
    if params[:approved] == "false"
      @users = User.find_all_by_approved(false)
    else
      @users = User.all
      authorize @users
      end
  end
```

Does anyone know what else needs to be done (besides whats shown in the tutorial) to get this functionality to work?

Comment: try `@users = User.where(approved: false)` let me know...

Comment: Thanks - that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you had typo issue. Below one should give you same results.

```
@users = User.where(approved: false)
```

Comment: I copied directly from the wiki post. Your solution works though, so thanks.

Comment: also, this one does same thing: `@users = User.find_by_approved(false)`

Comment: thanks - its strange that the example in the wiki tutorial is wrong